# Create specific list activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

How to create activity like this in Android?

http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/d76065ecb863b600ce966082837ca014.png

As you scroll up, the image also moves up, but more slowly. And its height degreas.

I'm new in Android and don`t know how to do such things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the list of items, that's probably a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

If you mean the fact that as you scroll up the background also moves up, but more slowly, that's parallax scroll. There are some libraries to achieve this effect, like [this one](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) or [this one](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid).

Answer (score 0):

it is called ListView... I recomend you to google a little bit more before asking your question...

[You can read more here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

regards...!!